# Ugly separators in toolbars - Ambiance - 13.04

Tags: themes, 13.04, ambiance

Can I fix or change the separators' color for ambiance theme in toolbars? it's always white even if I change every value of "separator" in every config file of ambiance theme to be dark/black/not-white. Thanks.

Image:

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is modify some lines the css called '*gtk-widgets.css*' located in folder */usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0*:

1. Open a terminal with ctrl+alt+T and write *sudo nautilus*.
2. Search folder */usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0*
3. Modify this lines in css called '*gtk-widgets.css*' (first, make a backup).

   - Add `-GtkWidget-wide-separators: true;` in *default* sector.
   - Replace `border-right-color: alpha (shade (*@bg_color*, 1.26), 0.6);` for `border-right-color: alpha (shade (*v*, 1.26), 0.6);` in *.separator* class.
   - Delete 
     `border: none;` and `color: @dark_bg_color;` in *.menuitem.separator* class.
4. Save and reboot your computer.
5. Done!

Comment: please put your the contents of the file into a public fileing system such as launchpad - otherwise your answer will be of no use if the link dies.  It is also work describing in detail what changes you have made to the CSS file.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! This worked like a charm! Since fossfreedom already pointed out a good thing, I don't want to duplicate it on the launchpad. Is it reported already? If not, I can do it. Thanks again!